# Map Enum to [Flags] Enum

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have an Enum, suppose:

```
public enum ItemStatus {
    Available, Unavailable
}
```

I have a method that returns a list of those TVs, based on a filter. And a filter is represented by an Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum ItemStatusFilter {
    Available = 1, Unavailable = 2
}
```

Question: what is a slick way to check if given instance of ItemStatus matches given instance of ItemStatusFilter?

I dislike the idea of assigning values to ItemStatus members (1,2) since it is not required by that enum. Right now my code looks as follows:

```
public static bool Matches(this TagStatusFilter statusFilter, TagStatus status) {
  if (status == TagStatus.Available && ((statusFilter & TagStatusFilter.Available) != 0)) return true;
  if (status == TagStatus.Unavailable && ((statusFilter & TagStatusFilter.Unavailable) != 0)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

What about something along these lines?

```
[Flags]
public enum TagStatusFilter {
    Available = 1 << TagStatus.Available,
    Unavailable = 1 << TagStatus.Unavailable
}
```

The goal is to reduce amount of code, and reduce coupling between types.

Does it feel like `enum TagStatusFilter` is misused here?

Answer (score 0):

i don't like it.. but it'll work:

```
        foreach (tv t in tvs)
        {
            if (isf.ToString().Contains(t.Status.ToString()))
            {
                //match
                Console.WriteLine("matched");
            }
        }
```

Comment: That may return false positives if one enum member name is also a substring of another member.

Comment: not in this instance, as the first letter of the enum is capitalised.
Caution is obviously advised, and I do say I don't like it.. but it will definately work in THIS instance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use bit wise operation, if you want to use flag attribute. I've written a blog post about this, I hope it could be useful for you.

http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/86/why-the-values-of-enums-are-bit-flag-in-net

Answer (score -1):

If two enums differs only in `[Flag]` attribute, then you can use for filtering `IEnumerable<ItemStatus>` type.

So you have strong reasons to use two enums then it better to filter with

```
public bool Matches(ItemStatusFilter statusFilter, ItemStatus status)
{
    return ((int)statusFilter & (int)status) > 0;
}
```

Comment: -1. You have not understood the difference between flags enums and regular enums.

Comment: What is the reason for duplicating enum?